# Open the File Manager from an android app

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

How can I redirect my app to open the File manager at a specific path ?

I've tried something like:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("*/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
    shareIntent.setPackage("my.package");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But I keep get the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(3591): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=*/* flg=0x1 pkg=my.package (has clip) (has extras) }

What is the correct intent filter, as I suspect *ACTION_SEND* is not the correct one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/whatever/path/you/want/"); // a directory
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Comment: But how can I start from a specific filePath ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't redirect to that specific path, it open the default File manager location. Also, I would have want it to open the File Manager Application, not a popup from inside the app.

Comment: Then I'm sorry to report that there is no standard/generic way of doing this. File Managers on Android all have their intents specifications and that's a mess I know. But you can't AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this days it's more like:

```
// Construct an intent for opening a folder
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(aDownloadFolder), "resource/folder");
// Check that there is an app activity handling that intent on our system
if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(aContext.getPackageManager(), 0) != null) {
    // Yes there is one start it then
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Did not find any activity capable of handling that intent on our system 
    // TODO: Display error message or something    
}
```